# drupal CCK: how to add a text filed whose value depends on other CCK fields on the same page?

Tags: jquery, drupal, cck

I'm facing this situation, where I have several CCK fields, and I want one of these fields to be auto configured depends on one/some of the other fields. 
For example: suppose I have the following fields:
Field1: [selection list]
Field2: [Date Picker]
Filed3: [Auto generated value depending on the selection of Field 2]
So my intent here is that depending on how the user picks the dates in Field2, I'll automatically generate and show some value in Field3.

I guess Field3 doesn't really need to be a CCK field, as it's actually not collecting any information from the user at all. What I really want is this "real-time feedback" where users can see what happens if they input something in the CCK fields.

Any idea?Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, other then the [computed field](http://drupal.org/project/computed_field) there is no way to assign business logic to CCK fields in Drupal.

If you want such business logic  to control your fields, then I suggest either one of two options:

1. Create your own field. This sounds harder then it is; the hardest part is caused by lack of documentation: it requires reading example code and trial and error. A nice tutorial can be found [at poplar](http://www.poplarware.com/articles/cck_field_module).
2. Create your own content-type with its own fields. This is, by far, the simplest. But it lacks the flexibility of CCK: you hardcode the fields on this content-type, so cannot re-use them on others. Views won't integrate in your module without writing your own views integration and search-indexing and other extensions often require additional work.

That said, I, personally, most often choose the last; I hardly ever need the configuration-guis and all the options and flexibility, when I am developing custom stuff for sites anyway, so why bother developing it?
A good example is the fact CCK fields can be singular *and* multiple: your architecture and its code will need to cover both, else stuff will break. Even if you know for sure you will never need multiplicity in a field, you'll still be spending hours developing it.